# android.content.res.TypedArray cannot be cast to java.lang.AutoCloseable

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a custom view like following which I have been able to reduce to:

```
class MyCustomView : FrameLayout {
  constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
    initView(null)
  }
  constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
    initView(attrs)
  }

  constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, @AttrRes defStyleAttr: Int)
    : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    initView(attrs)
  }

  private fun initView(attrs: AttributeSet?) {
    attrs?.let {
      context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyCustomView, 0, 0).use {
        if (it.hasValue(R.styleable.MyCustomView_my_custom_attribute)) {
          //...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the problem is I'm getting an Exception: android.content.res.TypedArray cannot be cast to java.lang.AutoCloseable when executing `obtainStyledAttributes` method.

The same method is used all over my project but this is the only place where it is crashing. Why is that?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I have realized that I was using the method `use` from `AutoCloseable` interface, but class `TypedArray`, which is returned by `obtainStyledAttributes` method, only implements it [since Android 31](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray#close()) and I am testing on a lower API.

On places where it is working I am using `use` method from `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0` library, which is backwards compatible.

So to summarize, I only had to add the following import:

```
import androidx.core.content.res.use
```

Just in case you don't have it yet, also add the dependency to your app/library's `build.gradle` file

```
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0")
```

Comment: Yikes, nice footgun. Somebody needs to report this to Google so they can introduce a lint check for this. I personally was not warned about lacking backwards compatibility.

Comment: And remember to import it from `import androidx.core.content.res.use` which is `TypedArray` extension, NOT (generic) `AutoCloseable` extension. Android studio may suggest two different `use` extensions.

Comment: @Boken That is such a good catch. For some reason the AutoClosable's `use` didn't even need an import for me...no `*` imports...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comments. Is there something missing in my answer? I already indicated to add that certain import as a requirement for that reason. But if I can improve it I would like to know how.

Comment: Not working with 1.10.1

Comment: @AlexS, why not? And after upgrade to 1.12.0 it also works.